# How to solve the problem of stepping on mine the first step clicking in Minesweeper game

Tags: java, minesweeper

there is a rule in Minesweeper that you cannot step on a mine with first click. I am done with the game but the problem is that the mines would be randomly generated before the first click, so it is possible to click on a mine with a first click. Any suggestions? Thanks!

```
    //This generates the mines
    public void makeMSMine() {
    int i = 0, coordX, coordY;
    for (; i < mscountMine;) {
        coordX = (int) (Math.random() * msFieldNumber);
        coordY = (int) (Math.random() * msFieldNumber);
        if (map[coordX][coordY] == msEmptyField) {
            map[coordX][coordY] = msMINE;
            i++;
        }
    }
}


@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    Object localObject = e.getSource();
    int xCoord, yCoord;
    String[] tmp_str = ((JButton) localObject).getName().split("_");
    xCoord = Integer.parseInt(tmp_str[0]);
    yCoord = Integer.parseInt(tmp_str[1]);

    if (map[xCoord][yCoord] == msMINE) { //game over when you click on where the mine is randomly generated
        showMessage("Game Over", userNameInput + ", you stepped on a mine~~~");
        flag = true;
        showMSMine();
        return;

    }
    dfs(xCoord, yCoord, 0);
    checkSuccess();
}
```

Comment: There is no way to prevent it. If it happens, rig the game to simply start over, with a new random placement of mines.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Hi, is there anyway I can possibly start the game after a mouth click?

Comment: ?"mouth" click?

Comment: I'm guessing that you meant "mouse" click, and yes, absolutely there is. The details will all depend on how you've rigged your program, but if this were my project, I'd create a `public void reset()` method in my program's model (the logical non-GUI part of the program) that resets the state of all fields back to their initial conditions, and then the view portion (the GUI) should follow suit.

Comment: Why not just generate the mines after the first click? Just check during your mine generation to make sure the random square isn't the one the user already cleared.

Comment: *"there is a rule in Minesweeper that you cannot step on a mine with first click"* Since when?

Comment: @AndrewThompson: since those dang mine sweepers unionized

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels oh yes, typed it wrong. Thanks.